# Which is best to use in oracle Query A like operator , case statement and instring function or reverse function in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-like, query-performance

I am in some Confusion to find which of these will improve the query execution time.
Data base and Table information:
I am using database which is hosted in remote location might be US.
Table is having approx 2 cr. records and having only 2 columns String format.
I wants to extract the data from that table using filters and some modification.
 in select statements.
DB_KEY is having unique key indexing

Select statement condition:

```
CASE WHEN  (INSTR(DB_KEY  , 'MsgOutMdlName' ) > 0) THEN 
    reverse(SUBSTR( reverse(DB_KEY) ,  INSTR (reverse(DB_KEY)  , '|' , 1 ) ,LENGTH(DB_KEY) )) || 'MsgOutMdlName' ELSE
    reverse(SUBSTR( reverse(DB_KEY) ,  INSTR (reverse(DB_KEY)  , '|' , 1 ) ,LENGTH(DB_KEY) )) || 'MsgInAttName'
```

Or

```
CASE WHEN  INSTR(DB_KEY  , 'MsgOutMdlName' ) > 0 THEN 
    SUBSTR( DB_KEY , 0, INSTR(DB_KEY , '|' , 1, REGEXP_COUNT (DB_KEY, '[^|]+')-1 ) ) || 'MsgOutMdlName' ELSE
    SUBSTR( DB_KEY , 0, INSTR(DB_KEY , '|' , 1, REGEXP_COUNT (DB_KEY, '[^|]+')-1 ) ) || 'MsgInAttName' end
```

Or

```
CASE WHEN  DB_KEY like '%MsgOutMdlName'
```

then any one of above code:

and in where clause:

```
 WHERE 1 = ( case when DB_VALUE is not null and 
 (DB_KEY LIKE 'TP|%MsgInAttName' or DB_KEY LIKE 'TP|%MsgOutMdlName') then 1 else null end  )
```

Or use like operator in where clause.

Please suggest me the best approach.
DB_key are having dynamic data values.

I have already use function based indexing but didn't get better performance.

Comment: Have you tried all those approaches to actually see for yourself which works best for your data?

Comment: Thanks for edit the content ..: :)

Comment: Yes Alex Poole i have tried all those approach but in my local system db not at remote db. I didn't find any performance improvement
I didn't have access to those servers.

Comment: Unfortunately the answer is, 'it depends". There are no universally correct strategies for performance. Otherwise the tuning experts wouldn't make the fine living they do. Although `like '%whatever'` is pretty close to being universally Teh Suck! except for small amounts of data. Anyway you need to talk to your boss and get access to a realistic (Production alike) environment. Nobody successfully tuned anything by coding some guesses in Development.

Comment: Thanks APC.
I will check with my manager regarding access.
but for now which can be best suitable or which one you will prefer on querying against 2cr records set.

Comment: Please suggest me thing i am not able to make call.
AlexPoole I have the access of prod database now. but i didn't see any improvement by using these methods. Some please suggest me the alternative way of it. 
Thanks in advance..